# Issue - Google API Calendar - G Suite - Service Account - PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts, google-calendar-api

I am having a real issue trying to connect to Google's calendar API using a service account. I have followed the guides but keep getting errors when trying to retrieve information. The steps I have taken are as follows:

1. Create a new project in the Google Cloud Platform Console
2. Create a service account under credentials with domain wide delegation
3. Add the client ID to the G Suite->Security->Manage API client access with the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
4. Enable the Calendar API under API's & Services
5. Used the following code:

   ```
   require_once('plugin/google-api-php-client-2.2.2/vendor/autoload.php');

   putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=inc/service-account-key.json');

   $client = new Google_Client();
   $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
   $client->setSubject('email@calendardomain.com');
   $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);

   $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
   $calendarId = 'primary';

   $calendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->get($calendarId);
   echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary();
   ```

With this I am just getting the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method." } '

When I replace the email address with the one I get within the service account the error changes to:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "Not Found" } ], "code": 404, "message": "Not Found" } } '

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you have the correct json file and that it has access to it?

Comment: If definitely has access to it as when I change the path to something I know doesn't exist it throws an error message saying that it cannot find the file. Do you think I should be seeing values from the json file when I var_dump($client) ?

Comment: The settings in the admin console can take up to 24 hours to propagate. I believe that should be the problem if you've done everything correct. Just give it 24 hours and try again. It has happened to me several times.